# Javascript only executes/calculates the use of brackets in the case of addition/subtraction but not in multiplication?

Tags: javascript, html

index.js

```
function insert(num){ // Calculator functions

  document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value+num
}
function equal(){
  var exp = document.form.textview.value
  if(exp){
      document.form.textview.value = eval(exp)
  }
}
function clean(){
  document.form.textview.value = ""

}

function back(){
  var exp = document.form.textview.value
  document.form.textview.value = exp.substring(0,exp.length-1)
}

function decimal(){
  
  document.form.textview.value = document.form.textview.value+num.toFixed(2);
  
}
```

(3)3 returns nothing when expected to return 9.

However, (4+3)/7 returns 1 as expected.

[As seen here](https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50233381791_2a3cebb4ed_o.gif)

Other information:
HTML used; ran and rendered via Electron.

Comment: (3)3 - has no operator. (4+3)/7 has 2. `/` in your case is the reason it works - and `(3)3` is just syntax error.

Comment: and those are "parenthesis" `( )` ... brackets are like `[ ]` - and curly braces are `{ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(3)3` - has no operator. `(4+3)/7` has 2. `/` in your case is the reason it works - and `(3)3` is just syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Any programming language computes arithmetic results based on operators and operand. Brackets just denotes the grouping of operands just like we do in **BODMAS** only here we just have `()` as brackets. In order to calculate result you have to tell a program the type of operation you want to perform based on your choice of operator (+, -, / , %, *). So in order to fetch a result of `9` for the expression `(3)3` you have to apply appropriate operator, in this case a `*` like so

```
(3)*(3) = (3)*3 = 3*(3)
```